# function for array returns null

Tags: javascript, arrays

The below function returns this output. But I can't understand why. Any clues?

`Output: {"A":{"antal":null},"B":{"antal":null},"C":{"antal":null},"D":{"antal":null},"E":{"antal":null},"G":{"antal":null}}`

Function is,

```
    function seriestat(){
        var statserier = {};

        $.each(globalSIEdata["#EXTRA"]["VERSERIER"], function(i, item) {
                    statserier[i] = {};
        });
        $.each(globalSIEdata["#VER"], function(i2, item2) {
                var serie = i2.substring(0, i2.indexOf('-')); 
                statserier[serie]["antal"] += 1;
        });
        return statserier; 
    }
```

Here is example from globalSIEdata:

```
{    "#VER": {
    "A-1": {
        "verdatum": "2017-01-03"
    },
    "A-2": {
        "verdatum": "2017-01-03"
    },
    "B-1": {
        "verdatum": "2017-01-03"
    },
    "B-2": {
        "verdatum": "2017-01-03"
    }
    "A-3": {
        "verdatum": "2017-01-03"
    }
```

}

Comment: You don't understand why a function that creates and populates an object returns an object?

Comment: what does `globalSIEdata` looks like? can you share some sample/minimal data for review/testing?

Comment: What is expected result of `statserier[serie]["antal"] += 1`?

Comment: You got to be setting `null` somewhere else, there's no way += 1 would ever get you `null`

Comment: Added example from globalSIEdata above. Want to count the number of lines per object where item begins with A, B, C etc.

Comment: @Andy Good job Andy. Reading the title would have told you that his issue was with the null aspect of everything. Comments like that are why we have to wait for a certain reputation before answering. Maybe they should raise it higher...

Comment: @Matt I've been here a while and I've found that titles are often wrong, or rarely give the concise information required to answer the question. In this case, you're right, the title did have the relevant information, but the question itself was vague as to the problem. I skipped the title and found the question lacking detail. But thank God you've got me to scapegoat for your issues with the SO rules and regulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the "antal" property thus it will be undefined, try something like:

```
statserier[serie]["antal"] = (statserier[serie]["antal"] || 0) + 1;
```

Alternatively you could try to initialize your statserier object as follows instead:

```
statserier[i] = { antal: 0 };
```

Comment: `undefined + 1` would get you `NaN` and he's getting `null`

Comment: Well the output he posted is stringified, and NaN stringified is null.